# Scaling a View in axml or c#

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Currently I am trying to create a little app with mainly a horizontalscrollview and a main view. The horizontalscrollview contains a linearlayout with a bunch of BoxItems defined in my BoxItem.axml file. One BoxItem is also displayed on the main view.

The Problem is that I need to shrink the items in order to fit the scrollview. I would like the items to automatically resize (with all its child views) to fit the parentview (in height).

If it is possible I would also like to implement a function the set the size in code (but that’s not my main concern).

BoxItem.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Box"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="Shelf"
        android:id="@+id/Shelf"
        android:textColor="#009900"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="ProductName"
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:textColor="#009900"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Barcode"
        android:id="@+id/Barcode"
        android:textColor="#009900"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:text="10"
            android:id="@+id/StockCurrent"
            android:textColor="#009900"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="/"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="#009900"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="10"
            android:id="@+id/StockMax"
            android:textColor="#009900"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the items to automatically resize (with all its child views) to fit the parentview (in height).

You need API 11 or above to scale a `View`. Usage like this :

```
 LinearLayout ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.Box);
 float scalingFactor = 0.5f; // scale down to half the size
 ll.ScaleX = scalingFactor;
 ll.ScaleY = scalingFactor;
```

But the scale size is difficult to calculate.

Alternative choice, it is suggested that use [CardView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/cardview/#Overview) to implement this function.